# Converting HTML content to PDF file using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, jspdf

Trying to automatically convert this  content to a pdf file. Based on how the rest of my code is setup, I have to have the button to click INSIDE the div that I want to export to pdf. Is this a problem? Here's what I have so far. When I click the button, it does nothing.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery('#generatereport').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML(jQuery('#lppresults').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="survey-results" style="display: none;" id="lppresults">
   <button id="generatereport">Download Report</button>
   TEST CONTENT
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you have JS into .html file?

Comment: @VictorArcas yes, that is correct

Comment: When I tried there is an error saying .fromHTML is not a function. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a problem. You can have the button inside the `div` element. Though you have some other issues. Here is the revised version of your code ...

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();
$('#generatereport').click(function() {
   doc.fromHTML($('#lppresults')[0], 15, 15, {
      width: 170
   }, function() {
      doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<div class="survey-results" id="lppresults">
  <button id="generatereport">Download Report</button> TEST CONTENT
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see that your code snippet works, but when I implement on my website, the button still does nothing. Inside of my #lppresults div is a lot more divs (not just text) - this shouldn't matter should it? Also, I'm doing this all on a page that only accepts HTML. The only way I've gotten my javascript to work is by changing $ to jQuery - should I not have to do that? I'm wondering if something else is interfering.

Comment: No, multiple divs shouldn't matter, neither `$` and `jQuery`. Make sure you place your script before closing `</body>` tag. also do you see any errors in console?

Comment: Hmm. My script is at the top of the page (it's on wordpress) so definitely before the </body> tag. Only 1 error on console but doesn't appear to be related. I even created a new test div with just text in it, and still didn't produce a PDF. Console also shows that jspdf.debug.js is loading properly.

Comment: whats the error? and you need to place the script (not the library imports) right before closing body tag (after creating all the DOM elements)

Comment: Tried moving the script below everything on the page and still no luck. The error I'm getting in console is for something called "hbpix" and says ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT. Looks like it's trying to grab something from stpix.media6degrees.com which I'm assuming is unrelated?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the jsPDF class : `var doc = new jsPDF();`

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();
jQuery('#generatereport').click(function() {
  doc.fromHTML(jQuery('#lppresults').html(), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170
  });
  doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>


<div class="survey-results" id="lppresults">
  <button id="generatereport">Download Report</button> TEST CONTENT
</div>
```